# </br> not working in firefox and chrome

Tags: html

break line tag is not working in firefox, neither in chrome. When i see the source of my page i get:

```
<p>Zugang zu Testaccount:</br></br>peter petrelli </br></br>sein Standardpwd.</br></br>peter.heroes.com</p>
```

However when i do view selected source, i get:

```
<p>Zugang zu Testaccount: peter petrelli  sein Standardpwd. peter.heroes.com</p>
```

It seems firefox is filtering break line tags out.

It works in IE7 fine.

Comment: 8 duplicate answers so far...

Comment: Not sure why this question is being voted down.  It's kind of basic but it's still valid and it might help someone else in the future.

Comment: i agree w/ outlaw, and i upvoted for that reason

Comment: `<foo>` is an opening tag and `</foo>` is a closing tag. `<foo/>` is opening&closing tag (so called self-closing). You should not use a closing tag without opening tag.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You're looking for `<br />` instead of `</br>`

Self closing tags such as *br* have the slash at the end of the tag.

Here are the other self-closing tags in XHTML:

- [What are all the valid self-closing tags in XHTML (as implemented by the major browsers)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97522/what-are-all-the-valid-self-closing-tags-in-xhtml-as-implemented-by-the-major-b)

Answer (score 16):

If you are trying to put space between two divs and `<br/>` is not working then insert this code (between the divs) to get the `<br/>` tag  working.

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

and add

```
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

in your css file.

Answer (score 11):

The br tag should be:

```
<br/>
```

Answer (score 11):

It should be `<br>` or `<br />` **not** `</br>`

Answer (score 6):

IE7 is more forgiving of incorrect syntax in quirksmode.

Instead of `<br>` or `</br>` it should be `<br />`

Answer (score 3):

That's because `</br>` is an invalid tag.   What you want is `<br />`.

Answer (score 1):

should probably be used only if you are writing XHTML. If you use validator.w3.org to validate the following as HTML 4.01:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p>
<br />
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This warning is generated:

Line 8, Column 3: NET-enabling start-tag requires SHORTTAG YES.

```
<br />
```

The sequence  can be interpreted in at least two different ways, depending on the DOCTYPE of the document. For HTML 4.01 Strict, the '/' terminates the tag '). However, since many browsers don't interpret it this way, even in the presence of an HTML 4.01 Strict DOCTYPE, it is best to avoid it completely in pure HTML documents and reserve its use solely for those written in XHTML.

Answer (score 0):

It should just be <br>.

Comment: <br> will work, but is a legacy tag.  You should use <br/> instead.

Comment: Depends on your DTD (Document Type Definition), pearcewg. It's perfectly valid in HTML 4.01 for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You want <BR> or <BR />, not </BR>

Comment: You mean <br> or <br /> - the latest standards are to use lower case for tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using struts set `escapeXml="false"`

Answer (score 0):

It’s not `</br>`, it’s `<br>` or `<br />.`

So, this doesn’t work as expected:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>
   Some text... </br>
   Some more text...
  </p>
  More content...
 </body>
</html>
```

But this works:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>
   Some text... <br>
   Some more text... <br />
  </p>
  More content...
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me `CSS` was an issue.

For this tag `display: none;` was used so `<br>` tag was not rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Well I would recommend not using `</br>` instead try `<br />`. Using `<br />` instead of `</br>` ensures proper line breaks and should work consistently across all modern browsers, including Firefox, Chrome, and Internet Explorer.

Also try this updated code:

`<p>Zugang zu Testaccount:<br /><br />peter petrelli <br /><br />sein Standardpwd.<br /><br />peter.heroes.com</p>`

I hope it would work fine with this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This answer is the same as (or very similar to) the accepted one. It would be better to upvote that answer instead of posting it again. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](//stackoverflow.com/privileges) to upvote answers that helped you.

Answer (score -2):

Alternatively to `<br />` or `<br>` you can use `<p></p>` or `</p>`