# How to grow a div horizontally by its content?

Tags: css, html, expand, autogrow

please, can someone explain to me, why the red div isn't expanding to the right? It stops where the screen ends. What do I have to do, to make it expand?

One thing that works is to "display: table-cell" the red div but I was wondering if there's another way and why this happens...?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head />
<body>
  <div style="background-color: #f00;">
    <div style="width: 2000px; height: 100px; " />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good discovery. This is very odd. I'd like to see if anyone comes up with a solution without using table-cell or float.

Comment: You could always use HTML instead of XHTML :)

Comment: @nailitdown I hope it's just a joke. I hate non-XML-serialised HTML. Personal opinion… :-p

Answer (score 3):

That is indeed bizarre. Try floating the outer:

```
<div style="background-color: #f00; float:left;">
    <div style="width: 2000px; height: 100px;" />
</div>
```

Comment: I think floating should only be used to... well actually to float something. Overusing float can become a big mess. Setting width to auto should work.

Comment: While I personally don't think floating is the only solution here, this works best across all browsers and table-cell doesn't. Down-vote removed. =)

Answer (score 2):

The div that it's contained in is smaller than 2000px. You need to do something like this:

```
  <div style="background-color: #f00; width: 2000px;">
    <div style="width: 2000px; height: 100px; " />
  </div>
```

Of course, now the inner div's width doesn't need to be specified unless it is different than the outer div's.

Answer (score 2):

Put `overflow: auto;` in the parent `<div>`'s style.

Answer (score 1):

Check with this one. it will expand the container as the text goes on...

```
    <div style="background-color: #f00; height: 100px; display: inline-block;">
      <div style="background-color: blue; height: 50px; white-space:nowrap; display: inline-block;">
        here is some content
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  <div style="background-color: #f00;">
    <div style="width: 2000px; height: 100px; " />
  </div>
```

Closing a DIV tag like that (i.e. a self-closing tag) will cause trouble.

It may be legal ([See this SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97522/what-are-all-the-valid-self-closing-tags-in-xhtml-as-implemented-by-the-major-b)) but in my experience it often causes strange behavior.

However, that is not the problem. The following code works in Chrome and IE9.

```
  <div style="background-color: #f00; display: inline-block; height: 100px;">
    <div style="width: 3000px; background-color: blue; height: 50px;">
        here is some content
      </div>
  </div>
```

`Display: inline-block;` tells the element to grow as much (or as little) as necessary.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sArvr/

This does seem like counter-intuitive behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're using this for, I'm assuming the div element is going to be the main focus of the page; if this is the case, you can take that `width: 2000px;` line and just apply it to the body instead of directly to the block-level element you want to stretch:

```
<style>
body
 {
width: 2000px;
 }
</style>
```

If this method doesn't work for you for whatever reason, creating a transparent pixel image and giving it the width you require should work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

The width of the inner div can change, I need to grow the outer one so I can't assign a width to it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like **max width of parent div is limited by browser screen width** even though child div's width grows beyond browser screen width. This is an odd discovery...

I suggest using float on parent div. (ref: [crescentfresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494104/how-to-grow-a-div-by-its-content/494124#494124)) I know for sure that table-cell does not work for IE6. And a quick test on IE7 on my machine doesn't work either although it should...

This should work. (EDIT: This doesn't work...)

```
<div style="background-color: #f00; width: auto;">
  <div style="width: 2000px; height: 100px; "></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

put  `<div style="min-height: 100px; " />`

when you grow the content more, our div should grow its size automatically.