# Using the XHTML closing slash (/) on normal tags?

Tags: html, xhtml

I was just wondering whether it is acceptable to close a common tag, eg. a `<span>` which requires no data using the XHTML closing slash to reduce markup.

So for example:

```
<span id='hello'></span>
```

could be written as

```
<span id='hello' />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't do that, `span` is not **self-closing** tag. Here are the self closing tags:

```
<area />
<base />
<basefont />
<br />
<hr />
<input />
<img />
<link />
<meta />
```

Comment: @jessegavin 's answer claims that <param /> also belongs on this list. Which one of you is right?

Answer (score 3):

No. [What are all the valid self-closing elements in XHTML (as implemented by the major browsers)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97522/what-are-all-the-valid-self-closing-tags-in-xhtml-as-implemented-by-the-major-br)

Answer (score 3):

There are `empty` or `self-closing` tags. Span is not one of them.

http://justinsomnia.org/2005/12/there-are-only-10-legal-xhtml-empty-tags/