# Difference between <textview></textview> vs <textview />

Tags: android, xml

I noticed that both syntaxes are acceptable. Is one older than the other? Is there any kind of difference (historical or what not)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between <tag></tag> and <tag /> in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726164/whats-the-difference-between-tag-tag-and-tag-in-html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are all the valid self-closing elements in XHTML (as implemented by the major browsers)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97522/what-are-all-the-valid-self-closing-elements-in-xhtml-as-implemented-by-the-maj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is basically a self closing tag and has no difference. For more details see: [What's the difference between <tag></tag> and <tag /> in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726164/whats-the-difference-between-tag-tag-and-tag-in-html)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there isn't a difference. Some people do it with a space after it (whether or not it is a `textview` or not). I automatically change it when I see it with the space after. Here is an example of it:
[image: Example]