# Ordinary closing tag and self closing tag in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags

> Can anyone tell about the Performance between ordinary closing tag and tag self tag in html?

```
<area />
<base />
<basefont />
<br />
<hr />
<input />
<img />
<link />
<meta />
```

I saw these from here([Using the XHTML closing slash (/) on normal tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373866/using-the-xhtml-closing-slash-on-normal-tags)).

Actually My Main question is why we use this ?

I read the answer from :[What's the difference between <tag></tag> and <tag /> in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726164/whats-the-difference-between-tag-tag-and-tag-in-html)

**the Answer is :**

> A self-closing tag has no children and no value for inner text (null):

**Is it correct?** Because We can write inner text in these fields

```
<input />
    <img />
    <link />
```

So I am still confusing. Please give me a clear answer.

Comment: If you have doubts about answers to a question that has been asked and answered several times, posting yet another duplicate is not the constructive way.

Comment: In XHTML, `<input/>` means `<input></input>`, so no, there cannot be any content.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as a self-closing tag in HTML.

There are elements with mandatory start tags (`<p>`). There are elements with mandatory end tags (`</script>`).

There are elements with optional start tags (`<body>`). There are elements with optional end tags (`</p>`).

There are elements with forbidden end tags (`<img>`). (No element has a forbidden start tag).

HTML 5 allows a trailing `/` character in start tags for elements with forbidden end tags. This appears to be for the purposes of satisfying XML junkies and poor syntax highlighting software.

You cannot substitute a `/` for a real end tag. HTML parsers will *tend* to ignore end tags for elements with forbidden end tags. (However, for example, IIRC, `</br>` can produce odd results)

---

> We can write inner text in these fields: `<input /><img /><link />`

You can't in HTML (or XHTML for that matter, they are defined as not being allowed child nodes).