# Don't refresh page when enter key is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having some problems with the enter key triggering a refresh of the page whenever there is input in a form.

The following code does not refresh the page if enter is pressed and if there is no text inputted in the text area (#input) but will refresh the page if enter is pressed and there is input in #input OR if the cursor is in the text area. I'm not sure what's triggering it, as #submit is a regular button.

```
<div id="forms" class="container">
            <form>
                Enter your verb here in plain (dictionary) form:
                <input type="text" class="input-sm" id="input"></input>
                <div class="radio">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="input-method" value="Hiragana" checked />Radio 1
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="input-method" value="Romaji" />Radio 2
                    </label>
                </div>
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="submit" value="Submit">
                </input
            </form>
        </div>
```

I'm trying to jquery to solve the problem, but need help in that regard. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: where's your script???

Comment: Sorry, I've just added it.

Comment: You've got a closing tag for a button that doesn't exist in there...

Comment: @cardboardtheory This is just a standard behavior of text input elements placed within a form. The form is submitted when `ENTER` is pressed on a text input.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can either add following script at the end of body

```
<script>
        $("form").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("call some function here");
        });
</script>
```

or you can just put your form tag like this

```
<form onsubmit="return false">
```

either way you will then have to write an onClick="SOMEFUNCTION()" to the input

also there is an error with an extra /button tag...remove that and instead use

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="submit" value="Conjugate" />
```

note the ending slash

Comment: The ending slash is totally unnecessary, this is not XHTML.

Comment: @AxelAmthor It's "Teemu" haha. Also Amol, thanks for the Jquery script, it works. I wish I could mark two answers but I'll mark yours because I happened to want pure JQuery without HTML, though both function perfectly!

Comment: @AxelAmthor Please see Quentin's answer about [self-closing tags and HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22452057/1169519). And the [specs](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/syntax.html#syntax-start-tag) ...

Answer (score 5):

simply change your html:

```
<div id="forms" class="container">
        <form action="javascript:void(-1)">
            Enter your verb here in plain (dictionary) form:
            ....
```

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bhneaqe0/) - works like charm

Comment: Thanks, this works! Can you explain what it does and why the other one didn't work? Also is there anyway to do this outside the HTML?

Comment: It explicitly will do "nothing" and since there's no return value of `true` on the "nothing", the form will not be sent. That's a "so-90th" solution for single-pager, that it often is just forgotten.

Comment: sorry, second part: go with @Amol's solution for pure JS/jQuery and none-html

Comment: Got it and thanks for the help. Just realized I don't even need a form element: I don't have a server to submit anything to, I'm simply using the buttons to execute javascript functions using JQuery.

Comment: @cardboardtheory having no form-element will likely cause errors / arbitrary results in IE - tests recommended!

Comment: @ Axel Amthor I have a doubt. If we add `action="javascript:void(-1)"` then the form will not be submitted even when we click on the submit button.. Am I right ?? What if we needed to submit the form on click of submit button ?? Just asking for my own knowledge.

Comment: Thanks, I'll experiment.

Answer (score -1):

you have syntax error in your html codes:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="submit" value="Submit">
            </button>
```

change it to this:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="submit" value="Submit">
            </button>
```

Also, you need using Javascript/jquery to submit your form to prevent refreshing your entire page

Comment: Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score -1):

place :
`e.preventDefault();`
inside the keypress function