# Cross Browser Issue

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, cross-browser

My background is in WinForms programming and I'm trying to branch out a bit.  I'm finding cross-browser issues a frustrating barrier in general, but have a specific one that I just can't seem to work through.

I want to display an image and place a semi-transparent bar across the top and bottom.  This isn't my ultimate goal, of course, but it demonstrates the problem I'm having in a relatively short, self-contained, code fragment so let's go with it.

The sample code below displays as intended in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.  In IE8, the bar at the bottom doesn't appear at all.  I've researched it for hours but just can't seem to come up with the solution.

I'm sure this is some dumb rookie mistake, but gotta start somewhere.  Code snippet...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .workarea
    {
        position: relative;
        border: 1px solid black;
        background-color: #ccc;
        overflow: hidden;
        cursor: move;
        -moz-user-focus: normal;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        unselectable: on;
    }

    .semitransparent
    {
        filter: alpha(opacity=70);
        -moz-opacity: 0.7;
        -khtml-opacity: 0.7;
        opacity: 0.7;
        background-color: Gray;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body style="width: 800px; height: 600px;">
<div id="workArea" class="workarea" style="width: 800px; height: 350px;
    left: 100px; top: 50px; background-color: White; border: 1px solid black;">
    <img alt="" src="images/TestImage.jpg" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; border: none;
        z-index: 1;" />
    <div id="topBar" class="semitransparent" style="position: absolute;width: 800px;
        height: 75px; left: 0px; top: 0px; min-height: 75px; border: none; z-index: 2;" />
    <div id="bottomBar" class="semitransparent" style="position: absolute; width: 800px;
        height: 75px; left: 0px; top: 275px; min-height: 75px; border: none; z-index: 2;" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are self-closing a `div` tag, which is not allowed to be self-closed.

You must close the `div` tag like this: `</div>`.

**Some browsers will support stupid mistakes like these, and attempt to close the tags for you. IE, on the other hand, doesn't.**

**Try this**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .workarea
    {
        position: relative;
        border: 1px solid black;
        background-color: #ccc;
        overflow: hidden;
        cursor: move;
        -moz-user-focus: normal;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        unselectable: on;
    }

    .semitransparent
    {
        filter: alpha(opacity=70);
        -moz-opacity: 0.7;
        -khtml-opacity: 0.7;
        opacity: 0.7;
        background-color: Gray;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body style="width: 800px; height: 600px;">
<div id="workArea" class="workarea" style="width: 800px; height: 350px;
    left: 100px; top: 50px; background-color: White; border: 1px solid black;">
    <img alt="" src="images/TestImage.jpg" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; border: none;
        z-index: 1;" />
    <div id="topBar" class="semitransparent" style="position: absolute;width: 800px;
        height: 75px; left: 0px; top: 0px; min-height: 75px; border: none; z-index: 2;" ></div>
    <div id="bottomBar" class="semitransparent" style="position: absolute; width: 800px;
        height: 75px; left: 0px; top: 275px; min-height: 75px; border: none; z-index: 2;"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've noticed IE dropping tags simply because it doesn't like how they're written in the code. Good eye.

Comment: Yeah, for a list of self-closing tags check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97522/what-are-all-the-valid-self-closing-tags-in-xhtml-as-implemented-by-the-major-br

Firefox and Webkit (Safari, Chrome) are smart enough to close those tags for you, which is why it worked in those browsers.

Comment: Just because you can rely on the browser to clean up your markup it doesn't  mean you should do it. Stick with the standards.

Comment: Rather, validate -for- the standards, since the validator is ideally a "multiple-browser-standards-check-in-a-can".

Comment: I knew it would be something stupid.  Nevertheless, your answer led me down an interesting path that ended with a better understanding of loose vs. strict doctypes and finding the w3c validator page which, had I known about it last night, would have identified this issue for me.  Thanks for all the comments, they were very helpful.