# Data after <textarea> is not shown

Tags: html, forms, textarea

If you go here: http://xcs.dyndns.info/piataterenuri/vinde.php you can see that the footer appears.

But if you go http://xcs.dyndns.info/piataterenuri/vinde2.php here, you can see that nothing is displayed after the textarea.

The only differnce betweeen that two is that the second one has:

```
<tr>
<td class="optiune">Info:</td>
<td> <textarea cols="30" rows="5" class="field"/></td>
</tr>
```

Why's that happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`textarea` tags are not self closing (in HTML). So your code should be:

```
<tr>
  <td class="optiune">Info:</td>
  <td>
    <textarea cols="30" rows="5" class="field"></textarea>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97522/what-are-all-the-valid-self-closing-tags-in-xhtml-as-implemented-by-the-major-br

Comment: Heh it's all good. Technically in XHTML you should be able to self-close any tag, so your only mistake was assuming that _should work_ means _does work_ :)

Answer (score 1):

a textarea needs a closing tag

```
<textarea cols="30" rows="50" class="field">
  PEW PEW PEW
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

you cant close textarea like this />

should be

```
<textarea cols="30" rows="5" class="field"></textarea>
```

it's not self closing like `<input />`