# Can the <script> tag not be self closed?

Tags: xhtml, html

I had this code in my website

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"/>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/lib/player/swfobject.js'></script>
```

swfobject was not working (not loaded).

After altering the code to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/lib/player/swfobject.js'></script>
```

It worked fine.

The document was parsed as HTML5.

I think it’s funny. Okay, granted a tag that is closed and a self-closing tag are not the same. So I would understand if jQuery couldn’t load (although I find it ridiciulous).

But what I do not understand is that jQuery loads but the following, correctly written tag, doesn’t?

Comment: It's interesting to notics how SO colours those lines. There really seems to be a (odd?) difference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97522/what-are-all-the-valid-self-closing-tags-in-xhtml-as-implemented-by-the-major-br

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In HTML, there are tags which are always self-closed. For example, `<hr>Some content here</hr>` does not make any sense. In the same way, there are tags which cannot be self-closed. `<script>` tag is one of them.

I am not sure about the reason of no self-closed `<script>` tags, but the reason might come from the fact that the tag was intended to always contain code inside. Again, I'm not sure.

Comment: 15 characters of yep. Same here.

Answer (score 27):

Because it gets parsed as:

Line 1: Start tag for script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"/>
```

Line 2: JavaScript (really broken JavaScript!) to execute if the external script mentioned on line 1 fails to load

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/lib/player/swfobject.js'>
```

Line 3: End tag for script started on line 1

```
</script>
```

> Okay, granted a tag that is closed and a self closing tag are not the same.

They are the same (if there is no content), but only in XML documents. An XHTML document served as application/xhtml+xml is an XML document. In an HTML document, thanks to a legacy of improper implementations by browsers, a self-closing tag is just a start tag (and so is only OK when the end tag is forbidden).

Comment: My mistake, @Quentin is right, Browser will identify line 1 (self-closing script tag) as a unclosed tag. For this case, line 2 is parsed as script content, line 3 is the end tag. If it can't find any '</script>' after line 1, it  marks all content after the line1 as script content. It can be tested in Chrome developer tool, just inspect the <script> element.

Answer (score 23):

[David Dorward's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531772/script-tag-cannot-be-self-closed/4531813#4531813) explains this from one angle, but there is a deeper reason why you can't do this:

### A slash at the end of a tag does not make it self-closing in HTML

The self-closing syntax is part of XML. In a normal HTML document, it has no meaning.

Comment: So things like `<br />` should never be used in HTML?

Comment: @Tom: It would be more accurate to say there's *no reason* to use them in HTML. "Should never be used" implies that it is problematic -- in fact, it is simply redundant, because the BR element is always self-closing in HTML.

Comment: @Chuck, late comment but, actually there is a good reason to make your html document also be valid XML document. Even if the browser does not care about the properly closed tags, making the document valid XML allows you to more easily parse and convert it (i.e. with XSLT).

Answer (score 3):

@Joe Hopfgartner: Did you alter the code to test if

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/player/swfobject.js" />
```

works? ;-)

**Update**:

Run the code and the `<p>` element gets hidden, so...looks like it works?

*HTML*

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>questions/4531772</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="4531772.js"/>
</head>

<body>

<p class="test">Testing...</p>

</body>
</html>
```

*JavaScript (4531772.js)*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.test').hide();
});
```

Comment: lol :) well it breaks th e following tag and neither of the scripts load ;)

Comment: @Joe Hopfgartner: I updated my answer above with the code I used to test this out.

Comment: interesting! i had one more css node after the 2nd script element which got killed ...