# How can I syntax highlight a custom self closing script tag in vim?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, dsl

I know that [normal script tags can't self close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531772/can-the-script-tag-not-be-self-closed), and I know less of vimscript than I might. I have been working with a custom XML templating language quite similar to HTML, and have been using the HTML mode along with the file `~/.vim/after/syntax/html.vim`:

```
syn region javaScript start=+<is:PageComponents:Script[^>]*>+ keepend end=+</is:PageComponents:Script>+me=s-1 contains=@htmlJavaScript,htmlCssStyleComment,htmlScriptTag,@htmlPreproc
syn region htmlScriptTag contained start=+<is:PageComponents:Script+ end=+>+ contains=htmlTagN,htmlString,htmlArg,htmlValue,htmlTagError,htmlEvent
```

The problem that I am experiencing is "spillover" of the highlighting region until the end of the file or the next closing script tag.

I have attempted changing start to: `+<is:PageComponents:Script[^>]*\(\\\)\@<!>+`, and `+<is:PageComponents:Script[^>]*[^\\]>+`, neither of which make a difference. As far as I understand regexes, the negative lookbehind should have been an ideal solution, and the one character match should have forced the greedy star to back off one character, resulting in failure. Replacing the `*` with `\{-}` for ungreedy behavior has the same result. What am I missing?

In case it's relevant, I'm running vim in Cygwin's mintty (type is xterm-256color), shell is bash, color scheme is [solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized).

Edit: Adding sample of our markup language

```
<is:PageComponents:Template title="Page Title" controller="controller">
    <is:PageComponents:Script src="/path/jsfile.js" />
    <is:PageComponents:Style src="cssfile.css" />
    <is:Containers:Box label="Box Label">
        <is:DataGridComponents:DataGrid id="data_grid_id" data_provider="data_provider" keep_state="true">
            <is:DataGridComponents:DataGridHeader />
            <is:DataGridComponents:Columns strip_placeholders="false" id="%%id%%_row">
                <is:DataGridComponents:Column header_title="Links Header">
                    <span class="popup-link popup-link-type1" id="type1_%%id%%">Type 1</span> |
                    <span class="popup-link popup-link-type2" id="type2_%%id%%">Type 2</span>
                </is:DataGridComponents:Column>
                <is:DataGridComponents:Column header_title="Data1">%%data1%%</is:DataGridComponents:Column>
                <is:DataGridComponents:Column header_title="Data2">%%data2%%</is:DataGridComponents:Column>
            </is:DataGridComponents:Columns>
            <is:DataGridComponents:DataGridFooter>
                <is:DataGridComponents:Pager id="pager_id" data_provider="pager_data_provider" for_component="data_grid_id" />
                <is:Containers:Box id="footer_box_id" data_provider="footer_box_data_provider">Text: %%data%%</is:containers:box>
            </is:DataGridComponents:DataGridFooter>
        </is:DataGridComponents:DataGrid>
    </is:Containers:Box>
    <is:PageComponents:Script location="onready">
    {literal}
        // Insert literal JavaScript code here for the page
    {/literal}
    </is:PageComponents:Script>
    {include file="path/file1.tpl"}
    {include file="path/file2.tpl"}
</is:PageComponents:Template>
```

Comment: You forgot a sample of your language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of my patterns worked correctly when I switched to using `/` instead of `\` in my match.

The corrected patterns are:
`+<is:PageComponents:Script[^>]*\(/\)\@<!>+` and
`+<is:PageComponents:Script[^>]*[^/]>+`.