# Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function

Tags: jquery

JS Beginner here. I've been trying to make slabtext on my website but I get the an error. No idea how to fix it.

```
$(window).load(function() {
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function
    slabTextHeadlines();
});


// Function to slabtext the hero panel
function slabTextHeadlines() {
    $('html:not(.ie8)').find('.slab').slabText({
        // Don't slabtext the headers if the viewport is under 380px
        "viewportBreakpoint":380
    });
};
```

Any ideas?
Pablo.

Comment: Post the contents of your `<head>` tag. You're probably not loading jQuery.

Comment: This indicates that most likely you did not include the jQuery library in this page, can we see the HTML too?

Answer (score 0):

did you library jquery plug in ? like jquery.min ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min" />
```

Comment: I think I may have a conflict with other libraries. Here is the link [link]http://www.starsdrivein.com.php53-6.dfw1-1.websitetestlink.com/ to the page.

Comment: i see i look into your code. you also have this jquery.slabtext.min.js
and this jquery.js?ver=1.8.3 <--- I think this is the one making conflict much better only one ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" > </script>
$(window).load(function() {
    slabTextHeadlines();
});


// Function to slabtext the hero panel
function slabTextHeadlines() {
    $('html:not(.ie8)').find('.slab').slabText({
        // Don't slabtext the headers if the viewport is under 380px
        "viewportBreakpoint":380
    });
};
```

Comment: You're missing the closing `</script>` tag. You can't self-close `<script/>`.

Comment: you are right : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531772/can-the-script-tag-not-be-self-closed