# jQuery reference from jQuery.com removes script from html

Tags: jquery

I have a html file with the following:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js" />
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Hello");
    </script>
    <h1>Test</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

when I open this in firefox directly from the file system the output is

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js" type="text/javascript">
    it loads the script here
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Test</h1>
</body>
```

I was wondering why the script tag is not loaded within the body.

It loads the script if my jquery source is from google cdn:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
```

I haven't hosted this page anywhere. Just trying some jQuery stuff and found this issue.

Comment: can you share the link of the page

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531772/can-the-script-tag-not-be-self-closed/4531813#4531813

Comment: check the console for errors. Maybe it's the missing doctype?

Comment: no erros in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

script tags are **not** self closing

change

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js" />
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
```

as right now the closing head, the starting body, and the next script until the closing script tag is all within the first script tag, and as that is a syntax error, the browser is probably trying hard to fix your mistakes.

Comment: That doesn't work. if I change the src to google cdn it works fine.

Comment: You should really install a WAMP server then

Answer (score 2):

You have to close the `<script>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
```

(instead of `<script ... />`)

---

Your code becomes (you see that even the syntax highlight was changed):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Hello");
    </script>
    <h1>Test</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Also, see the documentation:

#### [C.3. Element Minimization and Empty Element Content](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html#a_dtd_XHTML-1.0-Strict)

> Given an empty instance of an element whose content model is not EMPTY (for example, an empty title or paragraph) do not use the minimized form (e.g. use `<p> </p>` and not `<p />`).

I guess that [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4531813/1420197) will help you too.

Comment: It will be nice if you type the whole code in answer, sometimes it is difficult to perceive such error.