# How to call function in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying this effect in my .html file, but don't know how to call javascript ?

I've tried with   but that doesn't do anything.

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GM46N/185/).
This is the HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Tikitas </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
        <meta charset = "UTF-8" />

    </head>
<body>

<div class='header'>Header</div>
<div class='content'></div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a look at onclick methods and jquery document loaded

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the fiddle. Double check your JS' file name?

Comment: Please elaborate on `I've tried with but that doesn't do anything`. The fiddle link you provided is working fine.

Comment: @Bigood, I know that with JS file is alright.
But the problem is, that when I copy-paste it into my html file, the animation doesn't work.

Comment: @Decorian Always see the developer console tab (for errors) or the network tab (for missing files)

Comment: I've finally found out what was the problem. I haven't included jquery into my html.

Answer (score 0):

Close your script tag.

This:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">
```

Should be this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: @RahilWazir I didn't see that behavior a few days ago when my script wouldn't load (and I thought I had forgot HTML/javascript! :P). In the end it was interpreting everything after the <script> tag to be in it, thus not displaying any content on screen. Not tested, but you could at the very least make it a <script /> tag.

Comment: Just because there are sweepers in the streets doesn't make it okay to drop litter. I agree closing the tag regardless of whether the browser might do it for you is a must. For the two seconds extra effort that most IDE's do automatically anyway, it's far cleaner

Comment: I agree with @ScottMcGready, not to mention I've found lots of "documentation" (read blog posts, SO answers, etc) on the net detailing the necessity of a closing `</script>` tag. Take a look at [this website](http://blogs.perl.org/users/mike_friedman/2009/12/that-annoying-non-self-closing-script-tag.html), as well as [this Stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348736/is-writing-self-closing-tags-for-elements-not-traditionally-empty-bad-practice) and [this question too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531772/can-the-script-tag-not-be-self-closed).

Answer (score 0):

In the `header` part of your HTML structure, you'll need to put:

```
<script src=""
```

in the `""` you will put the path to your JavaScript file.

> If your JavaScript file is in the same folder as your HTML file, you'll just need to put the name of the file + the extension in the `src=""` part.

And after close it with the usual close tag `</script>`.

At the end it's suppose to give you something like that `<script src="path"></script>`.