# chrome extension Unable to add DOM element from Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to create a Chrome extension, which when clicked displays a text but I want JavaScript file to add that text(h1 tag) to DOM hierarchy.
In order to do that I have added a html file which should invoke the js file once the DOM is loaded.

Code:

**Manifest file :**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "MyFirstApp",
  "description": "This is Hello World App",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "hello.png",
    "default_popup" : "helloworld.html"
  }
}
```

**helloworld.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        h1 
            {
                text-align:center;
                font-size:50px;
                color:#089786;
            }
        body
            {
                background-color:#890541;
                height:100;
                width:500;
            }
    </style>
    <script src= "helloworld.js" />
    </head>
    <body>
    </body> 
 </html>
```

**helloworld.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  kittenGenerator.requestKittens();
});

var kittenGenerator = {

    requestKittens : function() {

        var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
        var content = document.createTextNode('text');
        h1.appendChild(content);
        document.body.appendChild(h1);

        var element = document.createElement('h1');
        element.innerHTML = 'teeeekst';
        document.body.appendChild(element);
    }
};
```

Comment: `<script src= "helloworld.js" />` is not valid HTML syntax. [`<script>` always requires a closing tag.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531772/can-the-script-tag-not-be-self-closed) Probably your final `</head><body></body></html>` is being treated as part of a script (instead of as HTML), so there's no `document.body`.

Comment: @apsillers I made the changes as you suggested but it is still not working

Comment: I commented out the following code var element = document.createElement('h1');
        element.innerHTML = 'teeeekst';
        document.body.appendChild(element); Now Its is working fine