# $_POST['projectSubmit'] not working

Tags: javascript, php

I'm tryig to echo a javascript after I hit the submit button to make sure that its working, but it only closes the modal and refreshes the page. What's wrong?
I also tried
'if($_POST[projectSubmit'] rather enclosing it on isset(). But it couldn't recognize the index 'projectSubmit'

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<div id="modal1" class="modal modal-fixed-footer" style="width:35%;">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Create Project</h4>
<div class="row">

      <div class="input-field col s12">
            <i class="material-icons prefix">perm_identity</i>
            <input type="text" name="projectName" class="validate">
            <label for="projectName" class="">Project Name</label>
      </div>

      <div class="input-field col s12">
            <i class="material-icons prefix">room</i>
            <label for="projectLocation">Location</label>
            <input type="text" name="projectLocation">
      </div>

      <div class="input-field col s12">
            <label for="projectType">Project Type</label><br>
            <input name="projectType" type="radio" value="Condominium" id="test1" />
            <label for="test1" class="black-text">Condominium</label>

            <input name="projectType" type="radio" value="Housing"      id="test2" />
            <label for="test2" class="black-text">Housing</label>
      </div>

</div><!--ROW-->


    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <input type="submit" name="projectSubmit"class="waves-effect waves-green btn-flat" value="s">
      <button type="RESET" class="btn btn-flat">RESET</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php
if(isset($_POST['projectSubmit'])){
echo "<script type='text/javascript>alert('JUJU');</script>";

}
else{
echo "<script type='text/javascript>alert('xx');</script>";
}


?>


</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not complete the single quote after text/javascript.
Please update that as follows :

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('JUJU');</script>";
```

and same as update the second echo :

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('xx');</script>";
```

Comment: Thank you for your amazing eyes c: But it when I click submit, it doesn't echo the alert? Why?
EDITED:
NEVERMIND. It's working perfectly now :D. I'll mark your post after 2 minutes c: Thanks!

Comment: Thank you ;) I tried this code and it works perfectly with echo the alert.

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect java script tag (missing quote)

Your code

```
 echo "<script type='text/javascript>alert('JUJU');</script>";
```

Correct tag

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('JUJU');</script>";
```

for refer [Can the <script> tag not be self closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531772/can-the-script-tag-not-be-self-closed)