# HTML does not show after adding script reference

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem. Without script reference html works correctly but when I add external js path to head part html does not work. here is my code

**login.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <script src="myscript.js" type="text/javascript"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form class="box login">

            <fieldset class="boxBody">
                <label>User</label>
                <select id='userlist' class="cjComboBox">                    
                </select>
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" tabindex="2">
            </fieldset>
            <footer>
                <label id='error' style='display:none;color:red;' >Check your password</label>
                <button class="btnLogin" onClick="login()" value="Login" tabindex="4">
            </footer>
        </form>


    </body>
</html>
```

**myscript.js**

```
function login(){alert('ok');}
```

Comment: what is the error you are seeing in console. Also check if the file is loading or not.

Comment: You should be closing your `script` with `</script>`

Comment: there is no any error nothing happen. if I remove script reference from head part everything is ok

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the <script> tag not be self closed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531772/can-the-script-tag-not-be-self-closed)

Comment: put closing `</script>` tag and ensure that the files is in the same directory or to write proper path to the file

Comment: thanks close `</script>` works

Answer (score 1):

All `<script>` tags have to end with an explicit `</script>` tag.

So you want to have

```
<script src="myscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```