# Difference between <script /> and <script></script> for importing multiple js file in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

This issue I recently faced, I was trying to import multiple js files in my HTML page like this -

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js" />
<script src="lib/js/backbone.js" />
```

But the issue I was facing is, it was loading only the first js file and the rest of the js file was not getting loaded. I also checked the network section in the browser, the remaining two file was just not getting called. Then I changed the syntax to this -

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="lib/js/backbone.js"></script>
```

And then the loading of all the 3 files happened successfully. My question is, is

```
<script src="" />
```

a wrong syntax or is this issue only specific to me?

Comment: Script tags are not self closing, you should have both opening and closing tag.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/97522/8448942

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531772/can-the-script-tag-not-be-self-closed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Script tag requires both the starting and ending tag. [From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script):

> Tag omission: None, both the starting and ending tag are mandatory.