# The text isn't showing up and the background color and text color is not the same

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
 background-color: black;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 1000px;
 font-color: white;
}

p1 (
 font-color: white;
)
```

The text won't show up when I run the code. I don't know what I'm missing but it's probably something small. Also, no, the text color is not the same as the background/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<title>Track Back Photography</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" style="text/css" href="trackback.css"/>
<script src="trackback.js" style="text/javascript"/>

</head>

<body>
<h1>About Me</h1>
  <p1>This is test text</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please post your CSS as well. You can use the Snippet button to post your HTML and CSS together so we can see the result.

Comment: Also your `script` tag is self-closing, which is not valid. Without any CSS at all the html does not render because of this. It should be `<script src="trackback.js" style="text/javascript"></script>` I think this is your answer, but I can't know for sure since you didn't share your CSS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can the <script> tag not be self closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531772/can-the-script-tag-not-be-self-closed)

Comment: if the script tag were the problem, would the background color still change? I had the background color set to black and the text as white and the background color worked.

Comment: Probably, since the CSS link appears before the script tag. I set this up in a snippet and naturally nothing rendered. Once I fixed the script tag, the html elements showed up.

Comment: so when you changed the script to <script src="trackback.js" style="text/javascript"></script> then all of the text appeared?

Comment: Precisely. Also it should be script type, not script style, although that won’t cause the page to not render.

Comment: so when you changed the script to <script src="trackback.js" style="text/javascript"></script> then all of the text appeared?

Comment: I just changed font-color to color in the css and the text appeared. Why wouldn't font-color work?

Comment: font-color is not a valid CSS property. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_color.asp

Comment: Oh, I thought it was. Anyways, thanks to you I have finally got my issues sorted out. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. Please consider upvoting and/or marking my answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here:

1) `<script>` should not be self closing. Change that to `<script src="trackback.js" style="text/javascript"></script>`

2) `p1` is not a valid HTML element. Change that to `p`

3) Your CSS has `p1 ( ... )` which is also invalid, as these parenthesis should be curly braces. Also, change that selector to `p` so that it reads `p { ... }`

4) You have `style` in your script tag, where you should have used `type` there.

5) Use `color` instead of `font-color` in your CSS.

Check out this working example:

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1000px;
  color: black;
}

p {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Track Back Photography</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" style="text/css" href="trackback.css" />
  <script src="trackback.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <h1>About Me</h1>
  <p>This is test text</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. I overlooked the p () in my css code and didn't notice that it was () instead of {} and I changed p1 to p. However, the text still is not showing. I also changed <script/> to <script></script>

Comment: You can see in my snippet that the text does show up, it’s just that you have to scroll down to see it. This is due to the 1000px font size of the `h1` tag.

Comment: I changed it to 20px but now all I see is the links, not h1 or p

Answer (score 0):

If you use background color black, then you should use color white instead of style of font. suppose style footer
`<style> footer { background-color:black;  color:white; } </style>`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1000px;
  color: black;
}

p {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Track Back Photography</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" style="text/css" href="trackback.css" />
  <script src="trackback.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <h1>About Me</h1>
  <p>This is test text</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).