# <script> tag must include separate </script> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scripting, src

I noticed today while doing some testing that the way I close my `<script>` tag either makes or breaks my page. For example, this works:

```
<script src="scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but this does not:

```
<script src="scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" />
```

The file appears to show up when I use IE's Developer Tools, but it seems like it just gets ignored. Has anyone ever seen this or know why it might be happening? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[You must include a closing script tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1).  The script element is not self closing, even when you're only including an external script.

Comment: Hmm. Now I'm wondering if one could do this: <script src="js">more js</script>

Comment: That would explain it! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The `<script>` tag can only be self-closing in *truly* valid XHTML documents – that is, a XHTML page served with the `Content-Type` of `application/xhtml+xml` – **and** when viewed in a supporting browser (IE8 does not qualify; IE9+ does).

In all other HTML documents, (**regardless** of what `DOCTYPE` is declared), the `<script>` tag is not self-closing and therefore **must** be closed with a `</script>`.

[Read more in this very detailed answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97522/what-are-all-the-valid-self-closing-tags-in-xhtml-as-implemented-by-the-major-br/206409#206409)

Answer (score 2):

I have also noticed you always need the `</script>`. It's probably because it requires content between the tags ("" counts), even though you're using `src`.

Comment: I wouldn't consider an empty string to be content. (At least, not in this context.)