# Self-closing tags in XML files

Tags: xml

`<tag id="foo" />`

I noticed that they work with PHP SimpleXML.

But all XML examples I found on the web close them the old way:

`<tag id="foo"></tag>`

Is there any reason why I should use the old method?

Comment: As far as I know, they are equivalent. The first method is a bit less verbose and saves you a few characters. You may also sometimes see `<tag id="foo" xsi:nil="true"/>`

Comment: I hate that nil="true".  As far as I'm concerned, `<tag />` means blank.  And omitting the element altogether means NULL.  It's just bloat keeping the tag and marking it as NULL.

Answer (score 48):

See the W3C specs for XML and XHTML:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-starttags
- http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html#a_dtd_XHTML-1.0-Strict

It depends on the Element Type declaration

> An element with no content is said to be empty. The representation of an empty element is either a start-tag immediately followed by an end-tag, or an empty-element tag.

but also

> Empty-element tags may be used for any element which has no content, whether or not it is declared using the keyword EMPTY. For interoperability, the empty-element tag SHOULD be used, and SHOULD only be used, for elements which are declared EMPTY.

This means, when your DTD contains something like

```
<!ELEMENT img EMPTY>
```

you **should** use

```
<img/>
```

unless you have good reason to use

```
<img></img>
```

Note that [SHOULD is defined in RFC2119](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt) as

> This word, or the adjective "RECOMMENDED", mean that there
>      may exist valid reasons in particular circumstances to ignore a
>      particular item, but the full implications must be understood and
>      carefully weighed before choosing a different course.

If you are working with XML that does not have a DTD or Schema, you can also influence how the XML is serialized with a [predefined libxml constant](http://www.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php):

> **LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG** (integer): Expand empty tags (e.g. `<br/>` to `<br></br>`)

But note that this option is currently just available in the functions `DOMDocument::save` and `DOMDocument::saveXML`, so you cannot use it with SimpleXml.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, it's not as simple as it seems at first.

## XSD differences:

First of all, it depends on your data type. If you use an XSD schema definition, which defines the types of your elements, then `<element></element>` **can actually only be used for string types**. Because, that's what it is, it is actually an empty string value: `""`.

Therefore, it is illegal to use `<element></element>` for an integer, while by contrast `<element/>` is applicable for all simple types.

## JAXB differences:

JAXB (Java XML Binding) has similar quirks. It would map `<element/>` as **different values depending on the target data type**:

- for String, it would be a ""
- for Integer, it would be a 0.
- for other types, it would just skip it.

You could be tempted to think that `<element/>` would resolve to a `null` value. But you actually need to use `<element xsi:nil="true"/>` for that. Which I have never ever seen in practice.

## HTML:

In HTML there is always that **third option of `<element>` without closing tag**. I don't know about you, but several times a day, I have to remind myself that HTML isn't just XML. And that actually means that `<br>` and `<br/>` aren't the same thing. You shouldn't use `<br/>` in HTML, and you shouldn't use `<br>` in XHTML.

## Angular 2+:

But what I really wanted to get to, continuing on the last statement, if you use frameworks like Angular2+ there is another thing to keep in mind.

Without diving too much in detail, Angular replaces custom HTML tags with HTML templates which are linked to components. However **it only supports the `<element></element>` format**. You're not allowed to use the `<element/>` format.

I personally try to avoid the `<element/>` syntax, because it has all the potential to make things go wrong. (= [bad aji](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bad_aji)).

Answer (score 2):

When you want to use PHP's [xml parser](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.xml.php), you can [specify actions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xml-set-element-handler.php) upon a start tag, close tag, or a complete tag. Based upon your wishes, you might want to have an action specifically on the close tag.

Answer (score 1):

In certain instances the separate open/close tags are necessary: as an example I've found that <script> tags in HTML need to have separate open/close to work consistently in some browsers. The separate open/close are a bit more verbose but worth it in those instances.

Comment: But that's HTML, which is not the same as XML.

Comment: Strictly speaking, (X)HTML is a dialect of XML. Browser parsing may be more relaxed in certain instances to handle badly-formed documents, but...it is still XML.

Comment: Strictly speaking, XHTML is an extension of HTML and XML.  However, it's recommended to only use self closing tags on elements that never contain content.  For example, to not use `<p />` even though it works in the major browsers (http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_3).  **HTML however is not a dialect of XML, it's an extension of SGML.**  XML didn't even exist as a spec when HTML was created.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same for XML, but may be different depending on your usage. For example, in xhtml1.0, there's an [official list](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp) for tags allowed for self-closing. As long as you do keep your doctype to the correct xhtml one, you should be fine. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97522/what-are-all-the-valid-self-closing-tags-in-xhtml-as-implemented-by-the-major-br) of stackoverflow for a more detailled explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Some simple serializers cannot handle self closing tags. For example boost::archive is good for Object Serialization, but has problems with formatted output from xerces-c.

Answer (score -1):

I know the thread is old but I did something easy that works, at least in C#.

pass in your xml document to this routine;

```
  void FillInTheBlanks(XElement root){
        foreach ( var xE in root.Elements().ToList<XElement>()){
            if (xE.Elements().Count() == 0){
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(xE.Value)){
                    xE.SetValue("UNIQUENONSENSE");
                }
            }
            else {
                FillInTheBlanks(xE);
            }
        }
    }
```

FillInTheBlanks(root);

convert document to string

var xml = root.ToString();

then replace the filler phrase with empty string

xml = xml.Replace("UNIQUENONSENSE", "");

tada, closing tags;