# When are closing tags required with Android view markup?

Tags: android, syntax, android-xml

For some Android XML attributes, you don't conclude the opening tag with a '>' until after you've inserted your formatting components. For example:

```
<EditText 
  android:id="@+id/etEmails"> 
</EditText>
```

Why is there no definition for the EditText component within the opening and closing tags?
Also, I noticed that some don't even require closing tags and are just in themselves XML statements. For example:

```
<Button
  android:text="Subtract 1"
  android:id="@+id/buttSub"
  />
```

Why does this XML statement not require a closing statement when it practically provides the same components as the EditText field?

- Is there a failsafe way of knowing which ones require opening and
  closing statements for proper syntax?
- Is there a list/reference for which ones do and don't?
- What's the difference between these different components?

Comment: I think it's a pretty good question. Not sure why the down-votes. XML can be fickle to get correct, especially when some elements/schemas just won't work with short tags. Grr!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<Button />` is a so called short tag. This is safe.

If a tag has no *body* you can obmit the closing tag and add a slash at the end of the tag which means here this tag has no children.

This notation is very common in xhtml for `<br />` and `<img src="" alt="" />` tags.

The benifit is that you don't need to write the closing tag which makes it simpler to read and if you have a huge xml file there are less data to transport. (This does not count for Android is this case, because the android SDK procudes internally a binary file.)

Comment: What about `<EditText />`, is that safe? Is it identical to `<EditText></EditText>`? If not, how not, and does it matter? If so, how to know which form to use?

Comment: That's [not strictly true](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231902/self-closing-tags-in-xml-files).

Comment: @pst you are right it can matter, but in this special case is no difference between the selfclosing and the normal tags. If not please tell me, I'm happy to lern something :)

Comment: I don't use Android XML :-) But I have run into cases where ASP.NET control markup will die horribly if a self-closing tag is used instead of an empty tag. Of course, that could also have just been a bad ASP.NET control .. (I up-voted this answer, but it would be nice to see some links to the Android view XML documentation, etc, justifying the usage of `<EditText />` in particular because that is what the question contains.)

Comment: @pst I aggree with you that a real referance would be nice, but I never read something about it in context of android. Even the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#write) simple uses the self closing tags without explaining why. The visual editor also uses them, just if you have a child node the normal tags are used.

Answer (score 0):

If no other element like this for example `<something></something>` is inside another element then the end tag `/>` can be used. So in your example the EditText can end also with the `/>` tag.

When you want to add another element to your EditText then you need to close the XML of EditText with .

Answer (score -1):

for '>' write in XML

please write as mention below

```
android:text="Subtract &gt; 1"
```

Comment: This answers some other question, but not this.