# Kotlin- xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" is unavailable

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I'm following the [kotlin fundamentals code lab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-images-compat/index.html?index=..%2F..android-kotlin-fundamentals#5) and in it it says that anything under API 21 will convert vector images to png images and to prevent that I need to add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` to the `activity_main.xml` file and press `Sync Now`, and add `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` to the `defaultConfig { }` in the `.gradle(:app`) file. I followed everything but I kept getting an error:

> /Users/Home/IdeaProjects/DiceRoller/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml:12
>
> error: attribute android:srcCompat not found.
>
> error: failed linking file resources.

I realized that the `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` line is grayed out

[image]

This is the gradle version I'm using:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha18
```

**What is causing this problem?**

activity_main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView 
           android:id="@+id/diceImageView"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:srcCompat="@drawable/empty_dice"
           tools:src="@drawable/dice_1">
</android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView>
```

build:grade(:app)

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.diceroller"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0-beta02'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
}
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha18'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: By the way, the problem that you've mentioned that you are facing is not related to the real issue that you're facing, which is defining the `srcCompat` property in the wrong namespace. (The greyed/grayed out namespace is because Android Studio recognises that the namespace is unused.)  The dependencies are also not related to the issue as well.

Comment: (P.S. The step that mentions that you should replace `android:src` with `app:srcCompat` is even mentioned further down in the step: "_Change the `android:src` attribute in the `<ImageView>` element to be `app:srcCompat`."_)

Comment: Ahhhhhhh, I didn't know. I just started learning Kotlin. I thought it meant it wasn't available. Now that I know it means it's not used I won't  ever forget it. THANKS for the info :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `srcCompat` attribute only exists in the `app` (`http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto`) namespace for the `AppCompatImageView` class (see the [API documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageView.html#attr_AppCompatImageView_srcCompat) for more info), not the default `android` (`http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android`) namespace.

To fix this, simply rename the `android` portion of `android:srcCompat` to `app:srcCompat`:

```xml
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView 
           app:srcCompat="@drawable/empty_dice" />
```

(P.S. Consider self-closing the XML tag such that you don't have to write more code to close the XML element. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066654/when-are-closing-tags-required-with-android-view-markup) for more info)

Comment: Yep you are correct, thanks for the help! And I'll take your advice about closing the tag the way you suggested.