# Visual Studio control closing tags

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Just a general curiosity, but is there any benefit to not having closing tags on controls in Visual Studio?

Does:

```
<asp:Literal ID="Description" runat="server" Text="PageText" />
```

have any advantages over:

```
<asp:Literal ID="Description" runat="server" Text="PageText" ></Literal>
```

other than being slightly cleaner?  Kind of surprised I can't find an answer to this anywhere.

Comment: No difference at all, it's simply a self closing tag vs none. It means less characters on the screen...that's about it

Comment: See this as well : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231902/self-closing-tags-in-xml-files

Comment: Thanks for the responses, good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Whether it is cleaner or not is a subjective answer.

For it really is a functional answer. If one plans on adding child nodes, the open one should be used. If most of the tags being worked on do not have children, use the closed option.