# How to read XML feed without closing tag using PHP

Tags: php, xml, feed

I am trying to read XML feed using simplexml_load_file function then reading each element

```
foreach ($source_xml->channel->item as $rss) {
    $title = $rss->title;
    $image = $rss->children('media')->thumbnail->attributes()->url;
}

<item>
    <media:thumbnail url="a.abcnews.com/images/US/…; width="384" height="288" credit="@TJReazor"/>
    <media:keywords>1</media:keywords>
    <title> 
        <![CDATA[ 5 Dead as Tornadoes Strike Dallas Area ]]>
    </title> 
    <link> 
        <![CDATA[ abcnews.go.com/US/death-toll-reaches-severe-storms-south/… ]]>
    </link>
    <guid> 
        <![CDATA[ abcnews.go.com/US/death-toll-reaches-severe-storms-south/… ]]> 
    </guid>
    <category>US</category>
</item>
```

But I am not sure how to read this element because it does not have closing tag as well as it has many attributes like url, width etc..

```
<media:thumbnail url="a.abcnews.com/images/US/…; width="384" height="288" credit="@TJReazor"/>
```

So, please let me know if anyone has tried to parse this using simple xml in PHP

Comment: Sample xml would help us help you....

Comment: Here is sample xml feed @cale_b                                                          <item>
<media:thumbnail url="http://a.abcnews.com/images/US/TL_Dallas_Tornado_151226_4x3t_384.jpg" width="384" height="288" credit="@TJReazor"/>
<media:keywords>1</media:keywords>
<title>
<![CDATA[ 5 Dead as Tornadoes Strike Dallas Area ]]>
</title>
<link>
<![CDATA[
http://abcnews.go.com/US/death-toll-reaches-severe-storms-south/story?id=35955662
]]>
</link>
<guid>
<![CDATA[
http://abcnews.go.com/US/death-toll-reaches-severe-storms-south/story?id=35955662
]]>
</guid>
<category>US</category>
</item>

Comment: it is a **self-closing tag**, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7232009/2016456 - how to read attributes with `SimpleXml` see http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [self closing tags in XML files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231902/self-closing-tags-in-xml-files)