# Is a closed tag that didn't open an issue?

Tags: xml

I have an `xml` that somewhere has a `<Comments/>` without `<Comments>` can this cause any problems? If remove it, is it okay?

Comment: `<Comments/>` is a self closing tag, basically start and end tag in one element. A closing tag would be `</Comments>`.

Comment: @Sirko Would you like to turn that valuable comment into an answer? For a really good one, some elaboration on how much troube such a self closing tag is (none, as long as it matches the schema) would be appropriate.

Comment: if the  `/` has a space after the Comments like that <Comments /> is it okay?

Comment: @user10201576 - yes, you're even allowed attributes.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Why the characters are read correctly in Notepad but with strange characters when opened in a browser for non English characters?

Comment: If you can remove it depends on your schema/DTD, if you have one for the document that is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Self-closing tags in XML files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231902/self-closing-tags-in-xml-files)

Comment: *what* non English characters (presumably non-latin-alphabet is intended)? Please stop morphing your question, especially when we have no idea what you're looking at.

Comment: YES you presumed correct, non latin.