# Is it OK to use a self closing DIV tag?

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are self-closing tags valid in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5)

For example:

```
<div id="myDiv" />
```

Something would then be done to populate this div using Javascript.

Is this valid HTML?

Comment: I would honestly say no. I feel that only certain tags can be self-closing in xhtml. These including <hr />, <input />, <img />. If it works though then feel free to use it.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

No. HTML 4.x doesn't have any concept of self closing tags.

It is valid in XHTML.

Comment: This is correct - also, for those of us using AngularJS or similar frameworks a self closing DIV will break the application in IE8.

Comment: What do you call img tags, then?

Comment: Just beware of using jquery as SOMETIMES it won't work right when you have a self-closing tag in a CERTAIN place.

Comment: @Stone - can you point me to an example/explanation?  I don't see that anywhere.

Comment: @gogogadgetinternet - At the time i wrote this, there wasn't any examples available. I learned it because I was hired to make six large AngularJS apps IE8 compatible (May no longer break IE in the current AnularJS versio, not sure). That being said, it looks like there's a proper AngularJS doc about IE now: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

Comment: HTML 4 theoretically does have self-closing elements via an [obscure NETTAG feature](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/empty.html): `<p/hello/` in SGML was the same as `<p>hello</p>`. The W3C DTD Validator supports this oddity, but no browser ever did.

Comment: @StevenLinn img elements are called "void elements", or in HTML 4.x lingo, "empty elements".

Answer (score 16):

Div's are not valid self closing tags. To have an empty div it would be better to do this:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 10):

According to the XML declaration and the XHTML 1.0 and 1.1 document definitions, this is fine: the null-end tag (`>`) may be used when immediately following the null-end start tag closer (`/`), and your code is equivalent to `<div id="myDiv"></div>`.

It's a different matter entirely whether any particular consumer will be able to process this correctly.

The SGML declaration used by HTML 4.01 allows tag shortening, but it has a different syntax for the null-end tags; there you can write `<div id="abc"/this is a non-empty div/`. Again, mileage may vary as for browser support. (My money is on "none".)

Future versions of HTML (HTML5? if that name is still alive) are no longer implemented as SGML languages, and therefore they simply allow what they say they do, without recourse to a formal grammar.

Comment: +1 for more detail. Maybe a corresponding link would be helpful ^.^

Comment: @Howdy_McGee: Check the W3C, they have the DTDs as well as the (multiple versions of the) SGML declaration for HTML 4.01, and also the (mandatory) SGML declaration for XML. On Linux, look in `/usr/share/xml` and `/usr/share/sgml`.

Answer (score 3):

Self Closing Tags in XHTML as implemented by browsers:

[What are all the valid self-closing elements in XHTML (as implemented by the major browsers)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97522/what-are-all-the-valid-self-closing-tags-in-xhtml-as-implemented-by-the-major-b)

Self Closing tags in html5:

[Are (non-void) self-closing tags valid in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5)

Answer (score 3):

I ran these two blocks of code through the W3C [validator](http://validator.w3.org). Copy and paste the code into the input under the Validate by Direct Input tab to see the results for yourself.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" >
  </head>
  <body><div id="Mydiv" /></body>
</html>
```

The code block with Doctype of transitional HTML 4.01 failed the validation process.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body><div id="Mydiv" /></body>
</html>
```

When I added the XHTML 1.0 transitional doctype, changed the meta tag to a self closing tag, and added in the html xmlns line, the validation passed.

So to answer the first half of your question, it is valid HTML under the XHTML 1.0 Transitional doctype. Whether or not you can use javascript to properly populate it, I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's valid XML (not HTML), and as far as I know, will only be accepted if the document is send with an application/xml mimetype.

However, it may work with XHTML, and the XHTML Doctype declaration.