# Prevent jQuery .html() from removing self closing tag slash

Tags: jquery

I'm sure most of you know the following:

```
var str = '<img src="path/to/some/image" />'

$('#selector').html(str);
```

This will output the following HTML:

```
<div id="selector">
  <img src="path/to/some/image">
</div>
```

It removes the self closing "slash" at the end of the img tag because jQuery renders true HTML, not XHTML.

My hands are tied into using a CMS that validates against XHTML so any markup that is copied into or created in the systems WYSIWYG must contain the "slash" at the end of a self closing tag.

My predicament is that I am using the [Bootstrap Form Builder](http://minikomi.github.io/Bootstrap-Form-Builder/) to create some quick and dirty forms. This application uses the jQuery .html() to create the rendered HTML. So all the < input > closing tag slashes are being stripped. When I copy and paste the rendered code into my CMS, it won't let me published it.

Anybody have a clever way to prevent .html() from removing the "slashes"? Or at least putting the slashes back in without having to manually do it?

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971716/is-it-ok-to-use-a-self-closing-div-tag) may help

Comment: plain javascript method document.getElementById also acts as the jquery.html

Comment: The issues is I have a CMS that requires the self closing tag "/>" but jQuery .html removes the / character. Therefore anything output by jQuery .html won't pass this CMS validation.

Comment: Which CMS do you use?

Comment: The University I work for uses Ektron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! Well, my co-worker did :)

There are a couple extra layers to this since I am using a Form Builder that is rendering the HTML to a textarea.

I had to use a combination of .text() and .html(). Instead of explaining it, here is a code snippet and jsfiddle link which showcases a very simplified version of what is going on:

```
$('#html').html("<input type='text' />");
var str = $('#html').html();
$("#renderHTML").html(str);
```

This will output `<input type='text'>`

```
$('#text').text("<input type='text' />");
var str1 = $('#text').text();
$("#renderTEXTHTML").html(str1);
```

And this one will output This will output `<input type='text' />`

http://jsfiddle.net/xMsgg/1/

Answer (score 1):

If I read [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/) I see the following text:

> This method uses the browser's innerHTML property. Some browsers may
>   not generate a DOM that exactly replicates the HTML source provided.
>   For example, Internet Explorer prior to version 8 will convert all
>   href properties on links to absolute URLs, and Internet Explorer prior
>   to version 9 will not correctly handle HTML5 elements without the
>   addition of a separate compatibility layer.

This makes me believe it is a problem with the browser you are using, rather than a problem with jQuery.

You can possibly use Tidy to turn it into valid xhtml. Googling makes me think that [this tool](http://infohound.net/tidy/) might be able to help you.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried multiple browsers and I got the same result. And I know it isn't an "issue" with jQuery, in fact as you can see here in their bug tracking they just dismiss it because that is the expected functionality and not a bug: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/3378

Comment: Not sure if Tidy will help me because the application I am using is just spitting out small snippets of HTML my users are copying and pasting into another system. I would rather not add an extra step for them to "clean" up the HTML/XHTML. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

This is not jQuery issue, native javascript `innerHTML` method works the same. Also this is not depends from DOCTYPE. I think it is browser feature.

Comment: I know it is not a jQuery issue, I was just hoping there was a work around because I NEED that self closing / character.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, another workaround is to replace `jQuery.html()` with `XMLSerializer` and its' `serializeToString` method.

As this is not using the DOM and innerHTML but treating your input as "regular" XML, all single tags are kept in tact.

See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer