# Google Map Div won't allow remaining/following HTML to render?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, google-maps-api-3

Does anyone know why my form elements are not showing up in the web page AFTER the div (id=map-canvas) to hold the Google Map - it's bizarre.  So in the example below it's not showing the "Confidence" field and the Submit button - any ideas??

BTW - if I put the div outside of the form - everthing renders ok.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Foo", FormMethod.Post, new { autocomplete = "off" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>FooLegend</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Confidence)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Confidence)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Confidence)
        </div>

        <div id="map-canvas"/>

         <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Notes)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Notes)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Notes)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>

    </fieldset>
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure `<div>` is a self closing tag.  Try changing to `<div id="map-canvas"></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are using XHTML, `<div>` is not a self closing tag.  In HTML 4 and 5, you cannot self-close `<div>`.  Try this instead:

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Ref.  [Is it OK to use a self closing DIV tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971716/is-it-ok-to-use-a-self-closing-div-tag)

Ref.  [Are (non-void) self-closing tags valid in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5)

Comment: Wow - such a dope, that just goes to show what can happen when you blindly copy code from help guides.  Thanks for that - changing that div tag sorted the problem nicely!