# css inline positioning of divs

Tags: html, css, positioning

i'm attempting to create an header which is divided into 3 divs 
they will all be set to display: inline-block 
the left header part will contain a slogan and a logo which i wan't the slogan to be at 
the right of the logo

**the problem is my logo div and my slogan div are always placed one on top of the other .**

to my understanding an inline element would be placed next to the last inline element 
with in the same block  , notice that the header-left div has 250px width and each of the 
child div's have 100px width  so why are they not placed one next to the other ?

my markup :

```
  <div id="header">
       <div id="header-left">
              <div id="logo" />
              <div id="slogan">
                 <span> Buy For U</span>           
              </div>
       </div>  
 </div>
```

my css :

```
div#header
{
    border: 1px solid black ;
    height: 200px;
}
div#header div#header-left
{
    display: inline-block;    
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;

}
div#header div#header-left div#logo
{
    display: inline-block;
    background: url("Google-Desktop-64.png") no-repeat center;
    background-size: 25%;
    height: inherit;
    width: 100px;
}
div#header div#header-left div#slogan
{
    display: inline-block;
    height: inherit;
    width:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

everything's fine. just close the logo's `<div>` properly. ["self-closing" tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97522/what-are-all-the-valid-self-closing-tags-in-xhtml-as-implemented-by-the-major-b).

```
<div id="header">
       <div id="header-left">
              <div id="logo"></div>
              <div id="slogan">
                 <span> Buy For U</span>           
              </div>
       </div>  
 </div>
```

i also suggest using an `<img>` for the logo (and make it a link to homepage) rather than just a background. empty `<div>` tags are prone to errors during validation.

Comment: a kinda want to die 
at least it does work like i think it does :)
thanks fskreuz

Comment: @eranotzer it's the simplest things we tend to overlook :)

Answer (score 0):

It is stange that your #header has a width of 200 pixels and the child #header-left 250 pixels, but apart from that I think it's better to use a float. This means that the two divs are next to each other:

```
div#header div#header-left div#logo
{
    float: left;
    background: url("Google-Desktop-64.png") no-repeat center;
    background-size: 25%;
    height: inherit;
    width: 100px;
}

div#header div#header-left div#slogan
{
    float: left;
    height: inherit;
    width:100px;
}
```

And you nead a clear in your html/css:

```
.clear_left { clear: left; }
```

And the html:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="header-left">
        <div id="logo" />
        <div id="slogan"><span> Buy For U</span></div>
        <div class="clear_left"></div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: i didn't wan't to use floats so i don't have to clear nothing
the headers width is not set and so it is a block which is automatically set to 100% width 

the others are just explanatory values to show that they do indeed fit.

Comment: @eranotzer Why don't you want to use floats? An inline-block is not supported by every browser.

Comment: i don't know how to . :) 
and i read that they should be avoided .
and when i was a child a float molested me from the left and right and the scars haven't cleared  to this day.

Comment: @eranotzer I don't recommend you to use inline-blocks, I think you should read this article: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-floats-101/ it is very informative!

Comment: @RemyStrijker actually you should go for inline-block. that's what it was made for: *"The element is placed as an inline element (on the same line as adjacent content), but it behaves as a block element"* http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp AND never worry about cross-browser compatibility. check this to see what's the lowest browser you should develop for compatibility http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201110-201112-bar AFAIK, only IE7 and older has issues with inline-blocks.

Comment: @fskreuz I see, but sadly there are people who use Ie7 but Ie8.  But Ie is always a problem! ;-)