# Why does <a id="test"/> breaks out of the DOM chain?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function fire() {
            console.log(document.body.children.length);
            console.log(document.body.children[0].children.length);
        }
    </script>
    <body onload="fire()">
        <div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer pharetra ipsum erat. Aenean convallis laoreet massa, et gravida purus faucibus ac. <a id="test"/>Vestibulum libero justo.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When you open the console, you'll see that the `<a>` is a `children` of `<body>`, `<div>` and `<p>`. WTF??

If `<a>` is closed with a "proper" closing tag the issue disappears and its only child of `<p>`.

Can someone explain this to me?

PS: Tested on Chrome stable.

Comment: It's because you can't self-close the `<a>` tag. The HTML is invalid and can act unpredictably.

Comment: Explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97522/what-are-all-the-valid-self-closing-tags-in-xhtml-as-implemented-by-the-major-b

Comment: Would it work when served with Content-Type "application/xhtml+xml"?

Comment: If you mean, would it self-close, and you'd not get the extra `a` elements when served with Content-Type `application/xhtml+xml`, then the answer is yes it would. And in spite of what Matthew says, it would indeed be valid XHTML5 (more formally, HTML5 in the XML serialization). You'd need to add the correct namespacing attribute to the html element though.

Comment: As a demonstration, here is your test case served as application/xhtml+xml: http://www.alohci.net/application/xhtml+xml/aron.htm.ashx . Notice in a Dom inspector that the `a` element does not "break out".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I imagine it's because `a` is not a valid short tag.

Comment: Specifically, `<a>` is not defined as `EMPTY` and therefore must have content

Comment: Would it work when served with Content-Type "application/xhtml+xml"?

Comment: Doubt it, it would still not be valid XHTML/HTML5, which the browser would be using.  You *could* parse it as XML, but the browser doesn't do this.

Answer (score 3):

As per the W3C recommdentations:

> 12.2 The A element [...] Start tag: **required**, End tag: **required**

It is invalid `HTML`. You need to at least close the tag directly after such as `<a id="test"></a>`.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html

Answer (score 1):

[`<a>` tags](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2) require an end tag (`</a>`).

`<a />` is invalid, and browsers will try to figure out what you mean, but don't expect consistent behavior.

Answer (score 1):

From [w3schools.com/tags/default.asp](http://w3schools.com/tags/default.asp) you can see self ending tags:

```
"area", "base", "basefont", "br", "col", "frame", "hr", "img", "input", "link", "meta", "param"
```

The `A` tag should not be self closed.

Comment: Didn't know it was the evil, but for such simple thing as tag ending, they should be quite correct no ?

Answer (score 1):

This is html5, not xml. Only [void elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements) are allowed to have such representation.
Also see 8.1.2.1 part 6