# 'Span' tag binding issues with knockout

Tags: knockout.js, html

I am fairly new to Knockout and can't get my head around this problem.

The HTML is:

```
<span data-bind="text: greetings" />
<input data-bind="value: firstname" />
<input data-bind="value: lastname" />
<span data-bind="text: greetings">Default 2</span>​
```

and the relevant JS is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dv = document.getElementById('divMain');
    ko.applyBindings(new Vm());
});

function Vm() {
    this.greetings = ko.observable("hello world");
    this.firstname = ko.observable("firstname");
    this.lastname = ko.observable("lastname");
};
</script>
```

([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j2E9G/4/))

The problem is that controls are not getting bound after the first span tag (greetings).

But if I enclose the span tag inside some `div` then binding works for every control.

Is this behavior common? Why controls beyond first span wouldn't bind?.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, only a few tags can be self-closing in html, if you serve your documents as MIME type `application/xhtml+xml` it would probably work...  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97522/what-are-all-the-valid-self-closing-tags-in-xhtml-as-implemented-by-the-major-b) has some good info.  Inspect [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SbbJ2/) and you can see that all the spans are nested.

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/j2E9G/) works for me...

Comment: Thanks mate, yes i was closing my span tag but like <span .../> , not with a </span> check [This](http://jsfiddle.net/j2E9G/4/)....dont know why is this the case :S