# Alternative to DIV for empty stylized tags

Tags: html, css

Let's say you had a page that utilized plenty of CSS to active the desired affect, however, that couldn't be done with secondary display traits like margin, padding, or border. For instance: you needed to create a div tag who's only purpose was of being a certain size, in a certain place, and a certain color; it needs to be `display:block`, and all those properties that can be pinned on div's due to their near universal use. The problem is, it's a waist to create all those `<div></div>` pairs if you don't need them. **Is there an alternative lone tag that can do those jobs that we usually delegate to div's and simply leave empty?** It would ultimately behave the same, stylistically, and look like `<tag/>`. Is there something like that; and would it be proper markup? Would be great if it was HTML 4 compatable too.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question on [self-closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97522/what-are-all-the-valid-self-closing-tags-in-xhtml-as-implemented-by-the-major-b).

From [here](http://dusan.fora.si/blog/self-closing-tags), `<div />` is valid (xhtml). I wouldn't do it though.

Comment: Yeh, figured I could, but I agree its a bad idea.