# why <iframe> and <textarea> cannot be closed like this />?

Tags: iframe, xhtml, coding-style

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are all the valid self-closing elements in XHTML (as implemented by the major browsers)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97522/what-are-all-the-valid-self-closing-elements-in-xhtml-as-implemented-by-the-maj)

If you're writing XHTML writing `<div class="whatever />` would be perfect and the page will continue to flow normally behind this `<div>` while writing `iframe` and `textarea` like this:

```
<textarea name="whatever" />
<iframe />
```

is considered invalid and the tags behind will be ignored as if the browser is waiting for these 2 elements to be closed?

What's the reason for this inconsistency? There must be a particular reason why these 2 particular elements cannot be closed like the `<div />` example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because they are not self closing tags. They have to to be closed after they are opened. See this as a reference

[What are all the valid self-closing elements in XHTML (as implemented by the major browsers)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97522/what-are-all-the-valid-self-closing-elements-in-xhtml-as-implemented-by-the-maj)

Also check as different types of tags here

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html