# Close HTML Script Tag

Tags: html, tags, external-js

I just curious why my JavaScript can't run (tested in Firefox and IE) if I write the `<script>` tag like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"/>
```

It will work if I change that line to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

So my question is: why I can't close the `script` tag in the start tag since I don't have any content inside it.

My JavaScript code is simple, just:

```
alert("test");
```

Notes: I check firefox error console and no error.

Comment: Script can't enclose itself. It's just that way. All DOM-elements that "can" have innerHTML, can't be closed on itself.

Comment: Compatibility depends on the _doctype_ - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97522/what-are-all-the-valid-self-closing-elements-in-xhtml-as-implemented-by-the-maj but browsers still vary on supporting self closing `<script/>`

Comment: @andyb — No, it doesn't. *Validity* does. Compatibility depends on *content-type*.

Comment: @Quentin Yes, I completely agree. A very poor word choice in my comment.

Comment: HTML tags are either self closing or not. It has nothing to do with the / at the end. That's an XML thing, not an HTML thing. So for example <script> is never self closing because it might contain a code block, and tags like <br> <img> and <meta> are always self closing. There is no such thing as a tag that is sometimes self closing and sometimes isn't.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The concept of self-closing tags is an XML concept. You can't use them in HTML. (You can use them in XHTML, but only if the document is served with an XML content-type, no[t if it is served as `text/html`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#C_2)).

In HTML some elements (such as `<img>`) cannot have any content, so they don't have end tags).

Since a script can have a `src` attribute or the script be can inside the element, `<script>` is not one of them.

(HTML 5 allows a `/` character to appear at the end of a start tag for an element that is defined as EMPTY, but it is just sugar for people addicted to XML and has no meaning in the language).

Comment: Can I use `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/xhtml; charset=iso-8859-1" />`?

Comment: No. `meta http-equiv` is a joke. You need a real HTTP header. You also need the correct content type (which is `application/xhtml+xml`). You should also use UTF-8, ISO-8859 has been long since superseded. I'd also recommend against XHTML since it will give you worse browser support, worse performance in browsers that do support it, and it sacrifices clean recovery from markup errors.

Comment: One more question, what do you mean `meta http-equiv` is a joke?

Comment: Because it is so far from being equivalent that you have to laugh (or cry).

Answer (score -2):

maybe u are using HTML 5 doctype, use html 4 doctype for this

Comment: That won't make a difference. You need to use an XHTML content-type.