# Replace br tags

Tags: regex, string, replace

I have multiple break tags throughout a string like so:

```
<br></br>
```

I want to replace them with a regular expression to be:

```
<br/>
```

These break tags will always have an opening and closing tag:

```
<br></br>
```

Comment: What language?..........................

Comment: You shouldn't use regexes to parse HTML. Are these strings into files or into a database ? In both cases, why not just use a simple find and replace ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure <br> is a [self-closing tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97522/what-are-all-the-valid-self-closing-elements-in-xhtml-as-implemented-by-the-maj). So just as a future ref, maybe just use `<br>`

Comment: No need of a regex, just replace `<br></br>` by `<br/>` literally.

Comment: I meant javascript. I need regex because of multiple occurrences in string. Dom document creates this <br></br> as a single tag, so I want to replace in in my javascript with this: <br/>

Comment: @zEro [Please stop linking to the “Zalgo” / anti-Cthulhu regex rant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182189/186921)

Comment: @sp00m thanks for the pointer. Deleting.

Comment: @Toniq You want to replace `<br></br><br></br>` with `<br/>` or with `<br/><br/>` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it

```
"a string containing <br></br> <br> </br> <br>".replace(/<br>\W*<\/br>/g, "</br>")
```

Comment: +1 nice use of \W for capturing the nonword characters.