# Unable to show text along side a drop down in bootstrap knockout webpage

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

In the second TR, text 'Minutes' is visible by side of TextBox, but in first TR, 'Minutes' is not appearing.

```
<div class="span6">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="i18nTranslateText: 'abc'"></td>
            <td>
                <select style="width: auto;" data-bind="options: pqr, value: abc.xyz" />
                <span data-bind="i18nTranslateText: 'Minutes'"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="i18nTranslateText: 'abc'"></td>
            <td>
                <input style="width: 25px;" maxlength="2" data-bind="value: dfe.eds" />
                <span data-bind="i18nTranslateText: 'Minutes'"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with Knockout:

you have [self-closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97522/what-are-all-the-valid-self-closing-elements-in-xhtml-as-implemented-by-the-maj) your `select` tag which results in invalid HTML so the browser interprets your `span` as the content of the `select`.

To fix this just properly close your `select` with `</select>`:

```
<tr>
    <td data-bind="i18nTranslateText: 'abc'"></td>
    <td>
        <select style="width: auto;" data-bind="options: pqr, value: abc.xyz" >
        </select>
        <span data-bind="i18nTranslateText: 'Minutes'"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```