# Why alert from external JS not appearing

Tags: javascript

Why no alert appear in the following HTML?

**My HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="a.js"/>
</head>
<body>

</body>
<html>
```

**a.js**

```
alert("hello");
```

Comment: Errors in the console?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8853550/2055998

Answer (score 8):

You can't have a self closing script tag. Change the script tag to:

```
<script src="a.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A `script` tag cannot be self-closing.  try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="a.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```