# Angular in an XML Namespace does not auto bootstrap via ng:app

Tags: angularjs, xhtml, xml-namespaces, backwards-compatibility, ng-app

I know that due to backwards compatibility with IE, Angular allows the use of an xmlns and using `ng:` instead of `ng-`, however it doesn't appear to be working with all directives in xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org">
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body ng:app="MyApp">
    <div ng:controller="FooController as foo">
      <p>{{foo.text}}</p>
    </div>
    <script src="angular.min.js" />
    <script>
      var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);
      app.controller("FooController", function () {
        this.text = "Hello Angular!";
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The above will just produce `{{foo.text}}`, but if I replace `ng:app` with `ng-app` (leaving `ng:controller` the way it is) everything works fine. I really like the consistency of using namespaces, so why doesn't `ng:app` work?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page explaining about `ng:app`? I can't seem to find it through Google.

Comment: @MrLister https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ng:app` syntax doesn't work due to the following:

> The elements contained within the template are always created in the HTML namespace. Whilst this is probably fine for the fast majority of cases if someone ever uses AngularJS with another XML document like SVG this could cause some problems.

**References**

- [Directive templates are always created in the HTML namespace](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5418)
- [XHTML pages with  fail to load in Opera](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7398)
- [AngularJS Developer Guide: Internet Explorer Compatibility](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/docs/guide/ie)

Answer (score 0):

Your example works fine. Have a look here: http://plnkr.co/edit/mgUMZe09FSr1aALE6ddd?p=preview

Maybe your `angular script` is not included properly

`<script/>` should be `<script></script>` its not self closing html tag

Comment: but the weird thing is that it works fine if I change the tag, I doubt it has anything to do with the inclusion of angular in some way

Comment: `<script/>` should be `<script></script>` its not self closing html tag

Comment: you do realise I'm using XHTML right? in XHTML self-closing tags are allowed for all tags, also using the HTML-style <script></script> doesn't work either in my browser, only changing from `ng:` to `ng-` seems to work

Comment: Good point. Anyway, xhtml and browser rendering is different question. Regarding angular everything works as expected

Comment: It works for me in Firefox 42 (OS X) as well if I copy paste plunker. Have a look at this (mime type) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97522/what-are-all-the-valid-self-closing-elements-in-xhtml-as-implemented-by-the-maj

Comment: looked at it, it parses it as xhtml, still doesn't work if I write `ng:app`