# Does frame tag need an end tag?

Tags: html

Should I put an end tag when using frame tag?

```
<frame name="a" src="a.php" />
```

Is the closing tag  **/** necessary?

Comment: Actually it's not even supported in HTML5. Use `<iframe>` instead.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/frames.html#h-16.2.2

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not even need the `/>` - [see here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frame.asp).

Please note, `<frame>` is **deprecated** in HTML5. It is highly advisable to use a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

> In HTML, the  tag has no end tag. In XHTML, the  tag must be properly closed.

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frame.asp

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/206409/2137833) answer.

Answer (score 0):

no need to put end of frame tag externally it is allready self closing tag