# Browser converts empty span tag to self-closed

Tags: html, css, apache-cocoon

I am using `<span class="class-name"></span>` repeatedly in my project. Something like this:

```
...
<span class="class-name"></span>
Some text generated here
<span class="class-name"></span>
Some text generated here
<span class="class-name"></span>
...
```

The purpose of the `<span>`is to have a `padding-right` so the text after it will be displayed nicer.
The problem is Chrome Browser can not render the empty `<span>` so it converts it to something like this:

```
<span class="class-name">
   Some text generated here
      <span class="class-name">
         Some text generated here
            <span class="class-name">
            </span>
      </span>
</span>
```

Which this will not result in the output I am looking for. Because the paddings will be mixed up.
The interesting thing is if you add a character like ​ between the  tags, the first view will be rendered by the browser and the problem is gone.
Could anyone please explain why its working like this?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: http://i.imgur.com/epR3pVB.png

Comment: Why would you use an empty element for spacing?

Comment: `<p>` elements trigger new lines by default anyway, so there wouldn't be any text to the right of the `<span>`.

Comment: Actually its not exactly a <p>. The process is more complecated than this. The code is written in .xml files and then its converted to html and some text is generated in the span.

Comment: Whatever the problem is, you removed it when you removed the complexity. You need to provide a real [mcve]

Comment: Ill try to reproduce it and add a link.

Comment: Don't add a link. Put the code needed to reproduce the problem *in the question itself*. [SO supports live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: "The code is written in .xml files and then its converted to html". Your problem is probably in that step, rather than when Chrome receives the resulting HTML.

Comment: It seems that cocoon it doing the translation to self-closing tags and then the browser converts the self-closing tags as the second view.

Comment: You need an `<xsl:output method="html"...` step at the end of your cocoon pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

had some trouble reproducing the bug, but that code seems to produce it

```
<span class="class-name"/>
<p>Some text generated here</p>
<span class="class-name"/>
<p>Some text generated here</p>
<span class="class-name"/>
```

your code however works perfetly fine for me, are you sure you are as verbose or did you used the **xhtml** [tag closing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/206409/8155150)

```
<span style="color:green"><span style="color:red"/> 
  If it's red, it's HTML. Green is XHTML.
</span>
```