# Why some non self-closing HTML elements that do not have a close tag (self closing) will not display these elements, but some do

Tags: html

1. `<textarea>` is not a self-closing element, right? If so, when I remove `</textarea>` in this [w3school code example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_textarea), why it still works?
2. There are only 12 self-closing elements based on [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8853550/8229192)? Is it complete? Does it means we have to add closing tag except these 12 self-closing elements? If not, then element cannot display correctly?

Comment: [Is this what you call "*working*" ?](https://jsfiddle.net/umrkznrk/) HTML5 is kind enough to almost never break on invalid syntax, and to build something valid from whatever your typed...

Comment: When I remove </textarea> in here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_textarea, then in the UI, we can still see textarea element works fine. This is what I mean.

Comment: make the textarea bigger, you'll see the `</body></html>` there too.

Comment: @Kaiido All right, I need to scroll down then can see </body></html>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Self-closing tags accompany [**void elements**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/syntax.html#void-elements), which don't allow any content within them.

The void elements are `<area>`, `<base>`, `<br>`, `<col>`, `<embed>`, `<hr>`, `<img>`, `<input>`, `<keygen>`, `<link>`, `<menuitem>`, `<meta>`, `<param>`, `<source>`, `<track>` and `<wbr>`.

Consider `<textarea> Text </textarea>`. That is **not** self-closing, because it makes sense for it to contain content; the text the user inputs.

Conversely, consider `<br />`. That is **self-closing**, because it's a line break; there can never be anything between the start and end of a new line.

Void elements have an **implied** closing tag if omitted; you can safely leave it out when writing the tag. `<br>` is just as valid as `<br />`.

**Omitting** the closing tag of a **non**-void element will still work in some circumstances. In fact, there's a list of **[optional start and end tags](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/syntax.html#optional-start-and-end-tags)**, that covers things such as `</body>` and `</head>`. This is because you **cannot** have a valid HTML document with these tags omitted, and if you choose to omit them yourself, the parser will **automatically** attempt to place them in for you. Inspection with the **[F12 Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589507(v=vs.85).aspx)** will reveal that these closing tags will be created automatically if omitted.

Obviously, this can be **confusing** for the parser, and it's much **safer** for you to add the tags in yourself. Otherwise, you may end up with invalid markup. You can test whether your markup is valid or not with the **[W3 Markup Validation](https://validator.w3.org)** service.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: <textarea> is not a self-closing element. Does this means we should always add </textarea> to a <textarea> element? If so, If so, when I remove </textarea> in this https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_textarea, why it still works?

Comment: Omitting the `</textarea>` would result in invalid markup. When you attempt to do this, the parser will **automatically** attempt to 'correct' this for you. If you inspect the element with your F12 Debugger, you'll find that the element has indeed been given an ending tag, even though you did not create it yourself :)

Comment: "Omitting the </textarea> would result in invalid markup" Although we have invalid markup, but parse correct it. So, we will not have any issue/bugs when we missing a close tag for a non self-closing element?

Comment: Whether or not you have bugs is **entirely** up to the parser. It is **inconsistent** between browsers, and should be avoided. `<textarea>` is **supposed** to have a closing `</textarea>`. If you write it in the correct place yourself, you will never have to leave it up to chance.

Comment: So, except above 12 void elements, we should always write close tag for other elements to avoid bugs? Or we had better write close tag for all elements?

Comment: "*Whether or not you have bugs is **entirely** up to the parser*" Nope, there are clear specifications on how parser should treat markup. In this case, everything after `<textarea>` is treated as being the content of the TextAreaElement, which should be treated as non-parseable text. Thus, this document doesn't have an `</body>` nor an `</html>` tag. In this case it is also specified that the parser must self-close this tags at the end of the parsing algorithm. So @CodeContributor except these 18 tags (`<html>` and `<body>` included), you **must** close all tags.

Comment: @Kaiido What is the parse here? Browser's parse? How can I find any info about parse?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn’t “work” when you omit the `</textarea>` end tag. Instead as @Kaiido alludes to above, “`</body>\n</html>`” gets added to the contents of the `textarea` element as text. Look:

[image: screenshot showing textarea eating markup]

As you can see there, “`</body>\n</html>`” has become part of the `textarea` contents.

That is, by removing the `</textarea>` end tag, you’ve caused all the remaining HTML markup in the source to be parsed not as markup but instead as text contents of the `textarea` element.

And while it’s true that for some elements, the parser will infer where the end tag should be and add it to the DOM for you, the parser will *never* do that for the `textarea` element.

> There are only 12 self-closing elements based on [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8853550/8229192)? Is it complete? Does it means we have to add closing tag except these 12 self-closing elements? If not, then element cannot display correctly?

Check https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-textarea-element and you’ll see that for the **Tag omission in text/html** section there for the `textarea` element it says:

> Neither tag is omissible.

Every element in the spec has a similar **Tag omission in text/html** section that explains whether or not you can ever omit the end tag or start tag for that element.