# Javascript: can't view an html file with javascript reference

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, frontend

I am trying to follow [this](http://web-engineering.info/tech/JsFrontendApp/book/) great tutorial of frontend programming.
I've come along building all the required files (until chapter 8), hopefully understanding most of the theory.

My problem is that when I try to open index.html in my IE11 I cannot see the page at all.

Only when I comment the following line inside the  of index.html:

```
<script src="src/model/Book.js"/>
```

then I can see the html visually.

Active Scripting on my IE is enabled.
Maybe it can be that my AVG Internet security is involved? I disabled its "Web Shield" feature - but no help.

Can you advise please?

Thanks!

Comment: Opening the DevTools (usually pressing F12), does some error appear?

Comment: Actually, despite what I said [`<script />` should work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97522/what-are-all-the-valid-self-closing-elements-in-xhtml-as-implemented-by-the-maj), but it depends on the doctype you're using.